# Do SQL synonyms work ok in multi user environment

Tags: sql-server

Using MSSQL 2008 - I have regular and archive table, same structure. 
Depending on the date range I create synonym to one or the other table inside stored proc, then use synonym for further data processing.
When two (or more) users concurently use stored procedure that uses synonym to different table, does second user overwrite where global synonym is pointing also for fist user or is synonym for first user unchanged during execution of his stored procedure?
If second version is true, then synonyms do not seem suited for multi user and dynamic synonym creation environment or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A synonym is merely a way to have one name point at another. I don't know what you're expecting, but any user that accesses the synonym by name will be accessing the underlying object that they synonym points to. Which, in my interpretation of it "working in a multi-user environment", means it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
It works, but the question is if it is usable in multi user environment, where the pointer of synonym is frequently changed between two tables. 
Hipotetical scenario : In simultaneous use of a lengthy procedure from 2 users - could the 1. user get the wrong result if sp for another user changed (global) synonym pointer while sp for the first user is running. Is this a possible scenario that prevents or at least discourages use of synonyms in multi user environment. 

I'm trying to anticipate possible problems before they occur.

Comment: The problem as you've defined it is a textbook definition of a race condition. You're almost guaranteed to have someone writing into the "wrong" table. My advice: don't do it and ask another question here specifying the business problem you're trying to solve.